# MongoDB aggregate $avg always returns zero

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get an average over a set of records from MongoDB, but it is always returning zero.

```
db.entries.aggregate([
  { $match : { "date" : { $gte : 1465672815466 }, "type" : "sgv" } }, 
  { $group : { _id : null, avgBG : { $avg: "sgv" } } }
])
```

I'm very new to MongoDB and I'm not sure if somehow this is caused by records coming back where there is no `"sgv"` value or if I'm doing something else wrong here.

Comment: You need to prefix the field's name with `$` `$avg: "$sgv"`

Comment: @Styvane, Cool.  Thank you.  Does my `$match` appear to be setup correctly? I.E. is it going to screen out records where the `type` fields is not equal to `"sgv"`?  If not this would really skew my averages...

Comment: Your `$match` is ok